# Linked Tkinter button to Sqlite3 database using classes

Tags: python, sqlite, class, tkinter

I'm trying to work on a Tkinter GUI with a backed sqlite3 database. I want to control the database with Buttons on my Tkinter window.
Also I'm figuring out, how to improve my code while using classes.
However, if I'm pressing the button "create database" no table is inserted into the database.

Following my code:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime

import os.path

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview, Separator


class MainApplication():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.title('Titanic DB')
        self.master.geometry('850x600')
        self.master.resizable(False, False)


        self.search_frame = tk.Frame(self.master).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_search_heading = tk.Label(self.search_frame, text='DATABASE |', font=('bold', 14), pady=10).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.button_create_database = tk.Button(self.search_frame, text='create database', command=self.ActionButtons, font=('bold', 14), pady=5, padx=50).grid(row=20, column=0, sticky=W)


    def ActionButtons(self):
        self.db = Database()
        self.createDB = self.db.CreateDatabase

class Database():

    DATABASE = "TitanicPassengers.db"

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(Database.DATABASE)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def CreateDatabase(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(Database.DATABASE)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Passengers(Survived INTEGER, " \
                                                    "PClass INTEGER, " \
                                                    "Name TEXT, " \
                                                    "Sex TEXT, " \
                                                    "Age INTEGER, " \
                                                    "SiblingsSpousesAbord INTEGER, " \
                                                    "ParentsChildrenAbord INTEGER, "  \
                                                    "Fare REAL ) " 
                    )

        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would be glad, if someone could give me a hint, what I'm doing wrong.
All additional tips how to organize my code better, are highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: By the way you aren't creating the `<tk.Label>` and `<tk.Button>` inside the frame. Split this line: `self.search_frame = tk.Frame(self.master).grid(row=0, column=0)` in 2. The `.grid` method always returns `None`.

Comment: You did not actually execute `CreateDatabase()` function in the line `self.createDB = self.db.CreateDatabase` because of missing `()`.  It should be `self.createDB = self.db.CreateDatabase()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out by myself.

I changed

```
self.createDB = self.db.CreateDatabase
```

to

```
self.db.CreateDatabase()
```

Nevermind, all tips for a better code structure are helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

self.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...etc

should be

self.cursor.execute..

is not it?